# For the minimum can we find a value of $n>0$ where $f(n)=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory

Let $r_1, r_2, . . . , r_m$ be a given set of positive rational numbers whose sum is $1$. Define the function $f$ by $f(n) = n −\sum_{k=1}^{m} \lfloor r_kn \rfloor$ for each
positive integer $n$. Determine the minimum and maximum values of
$f(n)$.

**Solution:** Of course $\lfloor r_kn \rfloor$ ≤ $r_kn$, so $f(n) ≥ 0$, with equality for
$n = 0$, so $0$ is the minimum value. On the other hand, we have
$r_kn − \lfloor r_kn \rfloor$ < 1, so $f(n) ≤ m − 1$. Here equality holds for $n = t − 1$
if t is the least common denominator of the $r_k$.

For the minimum can we find a positive integer $n>0$ such that for fixed rational numbers $q_is$ satisfying $q_1 +q_2 +..=1$ we obtain $f(n)=0$ ?

Comment: Can you formulate your question a bit more clearly?

Comment: Im basically asking if we can find a positive integer for which n satifies f(n)=0 for the minimum

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(n)=0$ for any $n$ such that $nr_k$ is an integer for each $k$. Clearly infinitely many such $n$ exist (if $r_k=\frac{p_k}{q_k}$, then take $n=q_1q_2\ldots q_m$ or any multiple thereof). In fact, it is for the maximum value that you have a problem: for any $x$, $x-\lfloor x\rfloor<1$ is a *strict* inequality, so we have always have $f(n)<m+1$.